# How to style a LineString feature to be red colored?

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, vector, geometry, linestring

I try to add Features with LineString geometries in different colors to a ol.source.Vector.

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
var myFeature = new ol.Feature({
   geometry : new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates),
   style : new ol.style.Style({
       stroke : new ol.style.Stroke({color : "red"})})
});
mySource.addFeature(myFeature);
```

The coordinates are correctly transformed. The resulting LineString Feature is displayed at the correct position in the map – but not in red.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For me it seems that this is not a matter of color but of `ol.style.Style` or `ol.style.Stroke` in conjunction with an `ol.Feature` or `ol.geom.LineString`.

Comment: Digging into the `Feature` object by debugging, I saw that the internal property of the feature `style_: null` after creation (new).

Comment: Does `myFeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({stroke : new ol.style.Stroke({color : "red"})}));` work after creation?
Is it really necessary to set the style for a single feature and not for the whole layer?

Comment: Does this work ? stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 1,
        })

Comment: no! I even tried `{color : '#f00', width:1}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot just set a style as feature property and expect it to work. If you set properties in the constructor, they will be feature properties. You can either use `setStyle()` on the feature after the feature is constructed:

```
var myFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: myGeometry,
});
myFeature.setStyle(myStyle);
```

or you can configure the vector layer with a style function that picks the style attribute from the feature:

```
new ol.layer.Vector({
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    return feature.get('style');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "red" in your stroke line, use the RGB value of red: 255,0,0

```
var myFeature = new ol.Feature({
   geometry : new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates),
   style : new ol.style.Style({
       stroke : new ol.style.Stroke({color : 255,0,0
    })
   })
 });
mySource.addFeature(myFeature);
```

Comment: The term {color : 255,0,0} is a js syntax error. I tried {color : "rgb(255,0,0)", "rgba(255,0,0,1.0)", "#rrggbb" and "#rgb" with no success. Even other styles (like width) are not recognised.

Comment: Is there possibly more information you could provide as to help solve why the color isn't not displaying?

Comment: The color syntax in the original poster's code is perfectly fine.